# Filter array of objects with sub arrays

Tags: javascript

I have next array:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    food: ['cola', 'pizza pie'],
    size: [{value: 12}, {value: 14}],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    food: ['water', 'wine', 'pasta'],
    size: [{value: 15}, {value: 19}],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    food: ['water', 'wine', 'pasta'],
    size: [{value: 1}, {value: 13}],
  },
];
```

I need to filter this array in the next way:
If I have the same 'food' values, the array item which has the highest 'size->value', should left, other removed.

Expected result:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    food: ['cola', 'pizza pie'],
    size: [{value: 12}, {value: 14}],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    food: ['water', 'wine', 'pasta'],
    size: [{value: 15}, {value: 19}],
  },
];
```

What is the best way for this?

Comment: What problems have you encountered?

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service, _you_ need to make an attempt. We are happy to help, if you run into problems with that, provided you give us a proper problem description.

Comment: What is the relation between the food and the size attributes?

Comment: it's portions of food

Comment: Editing your question to have it say _“What is the best way for this?”_ at the very end, does not make this any more appropriate. Please stop trying to weasel your way around the requirement, that we want to see _you_ make an actual attempt here first.

Comment: Surely there should be three entries in the `size` array for `['water', 'wine', 'pasta']`?

Comment: Here's your hint: map your top-level array into subarrays to put all the "same" items - items that have all the same ingredients in subarrays. Then sort those subarrays and take the first value from each of them.

Comment: Just try to do it! Even if it is not valid code we can at least have something to help with.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement as a little vague - particularly when you said:

> If I have the same 'food' values, the array item which has the highest 'size->value', should left, other removed.

But here is an approach using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (assuming the comparison is between the total sum of size values when duplicates are found). I've commented the code to give an idea on what's happening.

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    food: ['cola', 'pizza pie'],
    size: [{
      value: 12
    }, {
      value: 14
    }],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    food: ['water', 'wine', 'pasta'],
    size: [{
      value: 15
    }, {
      value: 19
    }],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    food: ['water', 'wine', 'pasta'],
    size: [{
      value: 1
    }, {
      value: 13
    }],
  },
];

function process(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const item = acc.filter(x => curr.food.sort().toString() === x.food.sort().toString()) // check if there is another entry with the same `food` value

    if (item.length) {

      // comparision logic goes here
      const previousSizes = item[0].size.reduce((a, b) => a + b.value, 0) // previous item's total size
      const currentSizes = curr.size.reduce((a, b) => a + b.value, 0) // current item's total size
      if (currentSizes > previousSizes) {
        return [...acc.filter(x => x !== item[0]), curr] //remove the previous item and add the new one
      } else return acc // don't change
    } else return [...acc, curr] // curr is a new item.. so just add it
  }, [])
}

console.log(process(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following sorts the input by food items to gather similar items together. It then walks the sorted input deleting items as it finds new maximums. It records the current maximum for each food grouping in a hashtable.

I think time complexity is `n log(n)` and the space complexity is `n`.

This implementation assumes the largest value in each size array is what you care about.

Pseudocode:

```
00. Create hashtable `hash`
01. Sort array `arr` by food
02. For each item `i` in `arr`
03.   Let `key` be a unique key for `i` based on food
04.   Let `largestSize` be the largest number in `i.size`
05.   if `hash` does not contain `key`
06.     Set value of `key` in `hash` to `largestSize`
07.   else 
08.     if `largestSize` is larger than hash.key
09.       replace `m` and delete previous item in `arr` because current item is larger
10.     else 
11.       delete current item in `arr` because it is too small
12.     end if
13.   end if
14. end for
15. return `arr`
```

```js
function filter(arr) {
    const hash = {}
    arr.sort(({food: a},{food: b})=>String(a).localeCompare(String(b)))
    for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        const {food, size} = arr[x]
        const [{ value: largestSize }] = size.sort(({value: a},{value: b})=>a - b).slice(-1)
        const key = String(food)

        if (!hash[key])
            hash[key] = largestSize
        else {
            if (largestSize > hash[key]) {
                arr.splice(x - 1, 1)
                hash[key] = largestSize
            } else
                arr.splice(x, 1)
            --x
        }
    }
    return arr
}

const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    food: ['cola', 'pizza pie'],
    size: [{value: 12}, {value: 14}],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    food: ['water', 'wine', 'pasta'],
    size: [{value: 15}, {value: 19}],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    food: ['water', 'wine', 'pasta'],
    size: [{value: 1}, {value: 13}],
  },
]

console.log(filter(arr))
```